# How many compositions of n with k parts are there in which each part is a even number except that a 1 may occur as a part at most once?

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find how many compositions of n with k parts are there in which each part is a even number except that a 1 may occur as a part at most once.

I have an example for the number of k-part compositions of n there are in which each part is an odd number and I'm assuming the solution is similar. Here is what I have so far

$$S=\{1\}(N_{even})^k$$

where $N_{even} = \{2,4,6,...\}$

$$\Phi_S(x) = \Phi_{\{1\}(N_{even})^k}(x)$$

$$\Phi_S(x) = x+(\sum\limits_{i\geq0}^{}x^{2i+2})^k$$

This is where I'm not sure I'm including the "1 may occur at least once" part correctly by adding the $x$. I'd appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Your S includes compositions in which 1 may occur any number of times (up to k).

Comment: hmm you're right should it be more like 
$$\Phi_S(x) = x+(\sum\limits_{i\geq0}^{}x^{2i+2})^k$$

Comment: That counts compositions in which either every part is even, or the composition is just the number "1" by itself. Hint: count separately the compositions with all k parts even, then those with first part 1 and the other k-1 parts even, then those with second part 1 and the other k-1 parts even, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm not very good at defining these and I can't figure out how to do what you suggested. I know the composition with all k parts even is $$\sum\limits_{i\geq0}^{}x^{2i+2}$$ but I don't know how to include the 1 part

Comment: In that case, stand back a bit from the generating functions, and think afresh: suppose you want to count compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts, where the first part is $1$ and the other parts are even. These compositions look like $n = 1 + 2a_1 + 2a_2 + \dots + 2a_{k-1}$. Stare at that equation, and see if it suggests anything. You can look at the answers to [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656873/how-many-compositions-of-n-are-there-in-which-each-part-is-an-even-number/656963#656963), and see if something from there might extend to here.

Comment: ok, so I want all compositions of (n-1)/2 into k-1 parts. So can I just substitute that into the solution for the number of compositions of n with k parts where the new n  (n-1)/2 and the new k is k-1 giving me ${((n-1)/2) -1 \choose (k-1)-1}$

Comment: Cool, now just make sure to multiply it by $k$ because the number $1$ can be in any of $k$ places. I'll post an answer as well

Comment: Ok so I think I have this figured out. It's the number of compositions of n where each part is even (1 occurring 0 times) if n is even (sum of even number is even). If n is odd (sum of even numbers plus 1 is odd) then it k times the number of compositions of n-1 for k-1 parts.

Comment: That's correct, good work. :-) I've posted an answer for you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1 (counting).**

The number of compositions of $n$ is $2^{n-1}$, via standard [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)): a composition corresponds to lining up $n$ stars in a row, and inserting bars in any subset of the $n-1$ gaps.

Similarly, the number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$: choose $k-1$ of the $n-1$ gaps to insert bars in.

The compositions we care about for this question are those that either

- have all parts even: $n = 2a_1 + 2a_2 + \dots + 2a_k$, which corresponds via the observation that $n/2 = a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k$ to an arbitrary composition of $n/2$ into $k$ parts, whose number is $2^{n/2 - 1}$ (if $n$ is even, and $0$ otherwise).
- have exactly one part equal to $1$, and the other parts even: this can be either the first part ($n = 1 + 2a_1 + 2a_2 + \dots + 2a_{k-1}$) or the second part ($n = 2a_1 + 1 + 2a_2 + \dots + 2a_{k-1}$)... or any part up to the $k$th part ($n = 2a_1 + 2a_2 + \dots + 2a_{k-1} + 1$). Note that all these compositions are distinct. In each case, any such composition corresponds via the observation that $\frac{n - 1}{2} = a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_{k-1}$ to an arbitrary partition of $\frac{n-1}{2}$ into $k-1$ parts, whose number is $\binom{(n-1)/2-1}{k-1}$ (if $n$ is odd, and $0$ otherwise).

So the answer is

$$\binom{n/2 - 1}{k-1}[n\text{ is even}] + k\binom{(n-1)/2 - 1}{k-1}[n\text{ is odd}].$$

---

**Method 2 (generating functions).**

Let $\mathcal{E}$ denote the class of all positive even numbers. We have a specification and consequent generating function for $\mathcal{E}$ as
$$\mathcal{E} = \operatorname{S\scriptsize EQ}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}\times\mathcal{Z})$$
$$E(z) = \frac{z^2}{1-z^2}$$
(Check that $E(z) = z^2 + z^4 + z^6 + \dots$ as expected.)

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the class of compositions of the kind we want. A specification for $\mathcal{C}$ is, considering the compositions with all parts even, and then with first part $1$, second part $1$, and so on:
$$
\mathcal{C} =
(\mathcal{E}\times\cdots\times\mathcal{E}) + (\mathcal{Z}\times\mathcal{E}\times\cdots\times\mathcal{E}) + (\mathcal{E}\times\mathcal{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathcal{E}) + \dots + (\mathcal{E}\times\cdots\times\mathcal{E}\times\mathcal{Z})
$$
which in simpler notation is
$$\mathcal{C} = (\mathcal{E}^k) + k(\mathcal{Z}\times\mathcal{E}^{k-1})$$
giving the generating function
$$C(z) = E(z)^k + kzE(z)^{k-1}$$
which with our previously found generating function $E(z)$ is
$$C(z) = \left(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^k + kz\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^{k-1}.$$

---

Note: it is possible to derive the coefficients from the generating function, or the generating function from the coefficients, but depending on what you're after (closed forms or asymptotics), it may not be worth going that route.

For example, from $C(z)$ we can get $C_n = [z^n]C(z)$ by calculating coefficients.
$$[z^n]\left(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}\right)^k = [z^{n-2k}](1-z^2)^{-k} = [z^{n/2-k}](1-z)^{-k}[n\text{ is even}] = (-1)^{n/2-k}\binom{-k}{n/2-k}[n\text{ is even}] = \binom{n/2-1}{n/2-k}[n\text{ is even}] = \binom{n/2-1}{k-1}[n\text{ is even}]$$
(would be a bit faster if you know beforehand that $[z^n]\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^r = \binom{n-1}{r-1}$) and similarly
$$[z^n]\left(kz(\frac{z^2}{1-z^2})^{k-1}\right)=k[z^{(n-1)/2}](\frac{z}{1-z})^{k-1}[n\text{ is odd}] = k\binom{(n-1)/2 - 1}{k-1}[n\text{ is odd}].$$

Comment: That is what I ended up getting in my solution. Thank you very much for your help in understanding this problem!

Comment: @guest: Sure, glad to help, and good that you were able to get to the solution on your own.